# Problem with IE Hash back button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I have an issue with ajax loading pages and the back button. I keep track of changes by modify the hash value. On firefox, I can get the back button to work perfectly by interval checking in javascript for the hash to see if it changes. On IE, I'm running into a problem where IE is not even keeping it in the history.

For example,

I have page:

a.html#a

Then I click:

a.html#b

Now when I press the back button, I'd expect it to go to a.html#a, but instead it goes back to the page before that. It doesn't matter how deep I get, it always go to the page prior to a.html#a.

What gives? I read some solutions and it appears I should load a hidden iframe somewhere on the page, but even that doesn't work. The pages in a.html are ajax loaded into a container on the page. Switching to iframe is not an option for me at this point.

Please help.

Comment: With a little searching, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078501/keeping-history-of-hash-anchor-changes-in-javascript) regarding hashes might be help. Seems to work on IE as well. If nothing else, you can use it as a resource for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some weeks ago.
See this SO issues:
 [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943989/back-and-forward-buttons-to-control-ajax-loads), and [a similar which helped me out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url).

I am using the j[Query history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) to handle that problem.

If you have problems implementing it, i can help you. but it was very easy.