# Change location.hash and then press Back button - IE behaves differently from other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, browser

I change `location.hash` - in all browsers this behave properly - the page remains original and changes only URL without reload the page.

Pressing Back button behaves differently in Internet Explorer and other browsers. IE does not change the history `location.hash` and goes to the previous page. Other browsers only change the URL (change the hash).

Is there any way to force IE browser to behave just like the others?

Comment: Of course it does, it's IE :)

Comment: Possible Dupe of [#4596769](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596769/problem-with-ie-hash-back-button). (CliffNotes: IE doesn't treat `#hashtags` as separate entries in the history object.)

Comment: @x0n: Firefox, Chrome and Opera behaves the same

Comment: thank you @jnpcl, I think [jQuery History Plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) will solve my problem

Comment: Also see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561975/backbone-history-is-not-updating-in-ie-9-back-button-broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Moving my comment here and expanding on it a little.)*

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596769/problem-with-ie-hash-back-button) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078501/keeping-history-of-hash-anchor-changes-in-javascript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url) regarding the `#hashtag` history quirks with IE.

Essentially, IE doesn't treat different `#hashtags` as separate entries in its History object.

The best solution appears to be the [jQuery History Plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).

Note- jquery history is no longer maintained and the former maintainers recommend [Jquery hashchange](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange)