# Hash links and History(Back and Forward)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, location, back

When I press on the hash button(e.g : http://test/#userid=1), I get the requested page but I can not return to previous page via the browser's back button. In Mozilla Firefox 5, the back button works, but not in others browsers.

I want javascript code or jquery code (Code not plugin if possible) to make the back button work in major browsers.

Comment: The back button not working with hash locations is news to me; which is a specific browser that's not properly implementing the back button?  I just tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: I see... in IE 9, if you started with no hash and go to `#userid=1`, the back button brings you back to the no-hash version, but if you start with no hash, go to `#userid=1`, then to `#userid=2`, the back button will take you back to the no hash URL, not `#userid=1`.

Comment: Jacob : I did not understand well, please explain again

Comment: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/crawling/
visit this link, it's work in all browsers
can you give the way in which the page (http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/crawling/) runs ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with IE Hash back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596769/problem-with-ie-hash-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) reports that it can solve the problem you're having.  It appears to use an iframe hack for properly preserving the history in IE.

Comment: Look at the notes for IE 6 & 7 in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078501/keeping-history-of-hash-anchor-changes-in-javascript/1091829#1091829.  The same technique is what the plugin uses.