# How do I disable back and forward button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable the back and forward action in the browser to my page.
So how to disable the back and forward actions of the browser.

Comment: On the face of it, this is a bad idea. More details on why you want to do this are encouraged :)

Comment: @JohnP - +1.  I thought part of the point of unobtrusive JavaScript was to give the user *back* his Prev/Next buttons, not take them away entirely.  : )

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+back+button

Comment: You could load everything with AJAX so that the actual URL isn't changing. I don't really see the use of it though - what is there about the back button that you'd like to disable it?

Answer (score 7):

You can't. This is not something a browser exposes.

Regardless, this is a usability nightmare - I wouldn't recommend this, as having the back and forward buttons are things that users are very used to.

You *can* write your application in such a way that it "breaks" if back is used, but I would suggest that this would make your application mostly unusable to most people.

Answer (score 0):

whatch [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url) 
and [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943989/back-and-forward-buttons-to-control-ajax-loads)

it's not exactly what you are looking for, but will give you an inspiration, how to react on user clicking back and forward buttons.

this jquery-plugin:  [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) is mentioned in both posts

Answer (score 0):

You can disable  going back to a page using the following script in the head of your html.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
   function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled here from a google search. Hopefully this'll help those with the same issue.

After the mandatory mention of this usually being an usability problem, that should be solved elsewhere, I've found this to work in chrome 85:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    history.back();
    history.forward();
    window.onpopstate = function ()
    {
        history.go(1);
    };
</script>
```

Lastrly, in all fairness, credit goes to the following thread:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8721521?msgid=10849294

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the back button by

```
window.history.forward(1);
```

Hope this helps...:)

Cheers...