# How do I change the address bar when I make an Ajax request?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, url-rewriting, struts2

I have created a website that intensively use Ajax to load its contents. 
I want the pages I select to load on AJAX but at the same time the URL also changes without reloading the whole page content. How would I achieve that?  I've googled already but my search did not yield any results.

Let's say I have this page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <sj:head />
</head>
<body>
    <h5>Struts Jquery Ajax Integration </h5>

    <div id="resultContent"></div>
    <noscript>Please Turn On Javascript to make the full use of this site</noscript>

    <h4>Choose A task</h4>
    <ul>
        <s:url value="views/ajaxvalidation.jsp" var="ajaxvalidation" />
        <li><sj:a targets="resultContent" href="%{ajaxvalidation}">Ajax Validation </sj:a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <h6>Play A Music while You Navigate</h6>
        <audio src="x.mp3" controls>Your browser does not support the
            audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I clicked the Ajax Validation link. it will not reload the page but however the url would be something like this:

```
localhost:8090/AppName/ajaxvalidation.jsp
```

or this:

```
 localhost:8090/AppName/ajaxvalidation.action
```

How would  I achieve such a goal?

*Note that I am using this plugin: [struts2-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)*

Comment: seems like you'd have to use some javascript on your handler code that processes the ajax response.  I don't think there's anything on the struts side to achieve this, if that's what you're thinking . . .

Comment: I think that's impossible;using ajax means that  you send a fragment of the page to the server,changing the url means changin the action

Comment: R U saying that you want to change the URL in the address bar of the browser when an Ajax call is made?

Comment: @chad Yup, that is exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/modify-address-bar-url-in-ajax-app-to-match-current-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

```
window.history.pushState(data, title, url)
```

---

**Update**

Noticing that you use `struts2-jquery` you can add `ajaxhistory="true"` to enable the build in ajax history functionality. See http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag#Attributes

```
<sj:head ajaxhistory="true" />
```

*Keep in mind, though, that it is not supported in all browser versions..*

Comment: Can you provide an example? just that snippet is not much making sense.

Comment: let's say I have set the ajaxhistory ="true" how would I then use it together with the window.history.pushState?  I am starting to get the idea but still no clue on the implementation. or I'll just use the said tag?

Comment: @KyelJmD Yes, ignore the `pushState`. I believe the `struts2` library handles this internally..

Comment: One thing I've noticed though, I can't seem to customize the url that is being generated, any solution to this? it is generationg a url something like this #resultContent=_sj_action_ajaxvalidationresultContent. I want to remove the sj_action. value

Comment: @KyelJmD, not knowledgeable enough about struts2, so i cannot help there.. nor how to intergrate `pushState`, as ajax calls are handled internally by the `struts2` framework..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState` if the browser supports ([read < IE10](http://caniuse.com/#search=history))

```
var boolPushState  = false;
if (typeof history.pushState !== "undefined") {
        boolPushState = true;
}

if (boolPushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, "URL");
}
```