# How can I make my web page not auto refreshing when comming back using back button?

Tags: html, http, browser-cache

I am developing a web page and I am testing it using httpd web server and Firefox. That page is a simple serach engine - providing key words and relevant items will be displayed using AJAX.

My question comes here, every time I click those items to go to another page and try to come back using the browser’s back button, all the contents disappeared and I have to search again.

How can I keep those items?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at google.com and what happens when you type but do not press enter.

Then  read this

[Modify Address Bar URL in AJAX App to Match Current State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/modify-address-bar-url-in-ajax-app-to-match-current-state)