# Possible to only update part of page and change query string parameters at same time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, query-string, partial-page-refresh, partial-postback

Is there a way to only update part of the page **and** update the query string parameters at the same time without completely refreshing the whole page in ASP.NET?

I only need to update the "main" section of my page and not the whole page. I understand I can do a partial page postback (or use asp ajax) to do the partial page update, but then how do I update the query string parameters in the URL at the same time? Is that even  possible?

Or is it not possible and I'll have to just do a `Response.Redirect` in the code behind of the partial page postback redirecting to the same page with new query params and just let the whole page refresh?

Comment: Do you want to change the actual address the user would be able to copy and paste, or do you just want to change the querystring parameters your page will receive?

Comment: @Renan - The actual address so users can copy/paste/share URL. However, all that's changing in the URL is the querystring parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1468/698202 might be worth a look "Modify Address Bar URL in AJAX App to Match Current State"

Comment: You should look into using HTML5 History.  See this question for good articles on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate

Answer (score 1):

Use pushState.

This new feature offers you a way to change the URL displayed in the browser* through javascript without reloading the page. It will also create a back-button event and you even have a state object you can interact with.

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Described [here](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Answer (score 0):

You have absolutely zero programmatic access to the address bar. The only way to change it is to redirect.

You could, however, do it like some sites do and provide a "send a link to this page to your friends" area. Youtube comes to mind - see how it provides a URL, querystring parameters included, for you to copy, should you wish to send someone a link to a video starting from some specific point.

Also check the handy "Share" link right under your question. You could provide a link like that, with the target URL, so for the user it's just a matter of right-clicking and copying from the context menu. A link well structured into your site is more user friendly than having the user copy directly from the bar, or from a text box. Specially for mobile browsers, where the sequence is usually press-and-hold, then copy. Copying from the address bar, on the other hand, may involve selecting the address bar text, which in some Android devices is a pain in the ass.