# Need to find this script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, linux

I'm trying to do new stuff for my websites (based on `PHP` - `Linux` server) and I wanted to do something like this website

http://equ.com.au/

I love the fact that each content load and it changes the `URL` directory.
What's the script used? I tried to google a lot of words combination but the only thing that came out were images slider, or page loaders (all those stuff that I can't find when I need them).

Hope to get an answer soon.

C YA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/modify-address-bar-url-in-ajax-app-to-match-current-state and some similar questions... Words could be: 'ajax/javascript url change without page reload'...

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned reference site ( http://equ.com.au ), this is single-page application. you need to try google for building single-page app.

But you want to change `URL` you need to write custom code in 'JavaScript'. Like this .

```
location.hash = "contact-us";
```

You should reefer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

and use any 'Jquery' plugin for make slider.

Let me know if any query, Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript history plugin to achieve this because it very difficult to manage data with browser hashes. You can use this https://github.com/browserstate/history.js